# Heroku not updating css for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm having trouble updating my rails app on heroku.  I've gotten my app up but I tried to change my application.css file in /public/stylesheets/ but whenever I try to push to heroku, the CSS never changes.  I tested these changes locally and they work just fine, I just can't figure out how to push them to heroku.  I've tried pushing with    git push heroku, heroku db:push, and heroku rake db:migrate but nothing works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea, I've done that to no avail. Still got the old stuff up

Comment: Are you pushing the master branch?

Comment: Yes I am.  When I do git push heroku master, it keeps returning Everything up-to-date even though everything isn't up to date

Comment: I came here looking for the solution to this problem. In my case, most of my CSS changed but not a few recent selectors. It turned out I had ran rake assets:precompile before making those changes. I ran rake assets:precompile again to include them, then committed and pushed to Heroku. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember that you have to commit the changes locally before you can push them.

If you do a `git status`, it should be clean.

If it's not (my prediction):

```
git commit -am "Your commit message"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I completely forgot about committing changes.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 43):

Each time you make changes on your CSS you need to run the following commands on the terminal:

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile
$git add . 
$git commit -m "msg" 
$git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because a previous developer had set up to do compiles locally instead of at deploy time.  I had a manifest file that I needed to delete:

```
public/assets/manifest-<md5 hash>.json
```

Once I deleted that and pushed, heroku built my assets.

Answer (score 2):

If you have recently deleted a css file, you should also use 'git rm' to ensure that it has been removed from your repository. Otherwise heroku may still use it.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread, but I got here having the same issue so I think it's still relevant to others. Check that the .css file is not simply cached by the browser you're testing on. By re-visiting the site in incognito mode you will be able to tell if a cached file is masking the changes.