# Rails, Heroku won't show either background image or background color

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I deployed my rails app (developed in Cloud 9) to Heroku, neither background image, or background color will show. (from the css file)

How can this be fixed?
I have tried to precompile the assets. Originally the background color would show, but not the background pic. Now nothing will show.

Application.css

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

 body{
    background-color:  pink;
 }
```

production env:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to        
    config/initializers/assets.rb
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Comment: Try setting   config.assets.compile to true rather than false.

Comment: I just tried that . Unfortunately I still have a white (blank) background :(

Comment: How about setting   config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

Comment: That's already there??

Comment: Hmm, so I see it in the code snippit you pasted twice. At the bottom it is set to true. Is that what is in your production.rb file? If so, remove the duplicate entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result. Blank background. I removed the server static assets

Comment: For kicks here is my production.rb from a working heroku app: https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/9eaa20c9171d75436f31d6fae3286e14 Also be sure you have gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production in you gemfile.

Comment: I copied your production file in. No change. I also have those gems

Comment: This is really strange. I have tried every which way, but it won't seem to even recognise the css background-color: somecolor;

Comment: Does it work on c9? Is your C9 workspace public?

Comment: It works in my Cloud 9 workspace every time. The problem is only on Heroku. Yes it is public

Comment: Can I pm my link? I am embarrassed at how basic my app is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. I thought I should share it in case anyone else is having the same problem. Please note that every time you run exec rake asset:precompile (if you're in Cloud9 anyway) it will navigate you back to your root directory. You have to go back into your app in order to add, commit and push.

reference: [Heroku not updating css for rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024712/heroku-not-updating-css-for-rails-app)

Each time you make changes on your CSS you need to run the following commands on the terminal:

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile
$git add . 
$git commit -m "msg" 
$git push heroku master
```